# TFS nearly identical queries - only one works

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

In VS2012 Team Explorer Query Editor, I have two queries that are identical, except 
that the order of two of the criteria is swapped. (Both criteria are 'and ...' so 
order should not matter.) One query works correctly, but the other returns nothing. 
How can I see what's really going on?

Comment: Sometimes refreshing your work item cache on your local machine can do wonders. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716728.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The search terms in one of the criteria was different. There is a 'wide hyphen' in the particular field in the work items. One of my queries had the search term with the wide hyphen, so it matched items. The search term in the non-working query was entered from the keyboard, and contained a narrow hyphen, so it didn't match an items.

I realize this doesn't really 'answer the question'. (How can I see what's really going on with the two queries?) But hopefully, if anyone else is having a problem with queries, this will give them one more possibility to check.